org mode transclusion problem with just pulling desired object
I have an org-roam file with the following:
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       679c7f30-d1b2-4247-85d6-f2da24e92480
:END:
#+title: table-ex

#+name: test
Definition of test

And I want to use org-transclusion to embed just the following into another file:
#+name: test
Definition of test

With the following I pull out the whole contents of the file
#+transclude: [[id:679c7f30-d1b2-4247-85d6-f2da24e92480]]

and I can get just what I want by specifying the specific lines:
#+transclude: [[id:679c7f30-d1b2-4247-85d6-f2da24e92480]] :lines 6-7

but of course I don't want to have to specifly lines every time.
How can I tell org transclude to just pull out the two lines without having to specify the line numbers?

What is the value of org-transclusion-exclude-elements? If I read the documentation correctly, property drawers should be excluded: if they are not, please open an issue on the Github site. You might want to experiment with the per-transclusion :exclude-elements from that page. OTOH, I don't think you can use that mechanism to avoid the #+title: syntactically, nothing distinguishes that from the part that you want to include.

And you might want to try a "real" Org mode file (one with at least one headline).
